# Full calendar show only chosen date

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to know if its possible in FullCalendar to show only two chosen dates in week-view for example

```
1 Jan 2017  |  2 March 2017
```

not 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 Jan 2017

I made research how to move an event from one date to another for example from 1 Jan to 2 March, but didn;t found solution about that, I think only way to handle this kind of situation to move events between dates is to show just two dates like I explained in question

Comment: But it's a calendar, I don't understand why would you need to show only 2 dates instead the selected week (And you should also show us your code and what you tried so far)

Comment: yeah I will tell reason why I need 2 dates.
I made research how to move an event from one date to another for example from 1 Jan to 2 March, but didn;t found solution about that, I think only way to handle this kind of situation to move events between dates is to show just two dates like I explained in question

Comment: Please take a look at [this example](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/) it shows how you can create a 4 days view, and you can easily alter it to a 2 days view

Comment: But I want to show different dates in different month no just in between week for example 1 Jan and 1 March not 1 Jan, 2 Jan

Comment: Well in that case you can try to create 2 instances of the calendar (Day view, with the specific dates on each calendar) and handle the dragging and dropping events as explained in the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/)

Comment: yeah that would be one solution too , but when it's come to touch devices drag n drop external events causes problem

Comment: you could create a custom GUI where, if the date to be moved to is outside the current view, the user can select the date to move it to themselves (e.g. using a datepicker), and then you update the event data accordingly. P.S. What do you mean by "drag n drop external events causes problem". Is this a known issue, or just a problem you've had yourself? Why can't you use this?